# From Node.js event handler to generator

Tags: node.js, generator

I have this `monitor` object that raises an event every time data is found, by means of an event handler:

```
monitor.on("data", data => { /* do something */ })
```

I would like to replace this pattern by using a generator:

```
for await(const data of monitor.iterate()) { /* do something */ }
```

I know I can do this:

```
async function monitorWrapper() {
  const allData = await new Promise( resolve => {
    const _allData = []
    monitor.on("data", d => _allData.push(d))
    monitor.on("end", () => resolve(_allData))
  } )
  yield *allData
}
```

and call it this way:

```
for await (const data of monitorWrapper()) { /* do something */ }
```

But this negates the whole of point of using `yield` since I have to wait for all elements to be available before processing.

**In this context, my question is** : Is there any pattern that allows to yield as the `data` events are triggered ?

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this problem myself.

```js
const stream = new class {      // mock event stream
  async start() {
    while (true) {
      const ms = Math.random() * 100;
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
      if (this.handler) this.handler(ms);
    }
  }
  on(handler) { this.handler = handler; }
}

class Monitor {
  events = [];                  // store events
  resolve = () => {};           // resolves current outstanding promise
  constructor(handler) {
    handler(event => {          // binds event listener
      this.events.push(event);  // add event
      this.resolve();           // call resolve
    });
  }
  async *stream() {                                    // generator
    while (true) {
      let event;
      while (event = this.events.shift()) yield event; // remove and yield
      await new Promise(r => this.resolve = r);        // wait for next
    }
  }
}

const monitor = new Monitor(handler => stream.on(handler)); // bind events
stream.start();

for await (const event of monitor.stream()) { console.log({ event }); }
```